# How can i add extra attribute to the form in admin dynamically

Tags: python, django

I am using the django admin site for my custom application with no custom front end views.

I am doing everything in `admin.py`

In my one  model , i want to add extra text field in the `change_form` which won't be persisted but for doing some ajax request to some external site

but i am not able to know how can i add that extra field

i don't want to create new form because that is automatically done by the admin site

Is there any way i can add field in the code like this

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
   search = forms.CharField(label='search')  
   add search to existing code // here 
   return super(PersonAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options.

1. Extend/Customize the default changelist form as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form)
2. Customize the [changelist template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_list_template) and inject(dynamically add) the extra field in jQuery ready() event.

Comment: 1. for 1 , if i do the custom form then i lose all the options setting , themes , widgets which django admin form uses. 2. regarding 2 , r u talking about chnage_form_template because i want in the model new or edit page

Comment: 1) try extending it. So you will not lose all the properties. 2) This template only used in both the add/edit page.